# real time turn by turn navigation using Skobbler APIs on a Java app

Tags: java, api, skmaps

I am trying to develop a java app that will run on a Raspberry PI. Raspberry PI will be mounted on a vehicle and I will know my position through a gps device. To solve this, I’ve been thinking on a solution like this:

Use a Webview on my JavaFX app and use your javascript API to build a real-time turn by turn navigation app. However, I’ve seen that your web API is not as complet as mobile platforms APIs. My question is: Is what I am trying to do feasible using your APIs? If so, could you please give me a brief description how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript API is not a turn by turn API - that is currently something a bit too heavy for javascript to handle (it could be feasible but it's not commercially attractive right now).

In theory you could integrate directly with the C++ code of the SDK as that should be able to run on Linux (depends here on the gcc version used and the OpenGl support offered - send an email to dev@telenav.com with your scenario and they will advise you).

Or if you can run Android on the device then you can use directly the Android SDK.